# How do I make a cell in the middle of a tableview invisible?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

Ok I have an app that looks like this:

[image: Tableview]

What I need is to grey out or deactivate the cell at indexPath.row = 3, which is the "Off grid Est Daily Consumption" cell depending on the value of the switch.

I connected the switch and have its valueChanged method as an IBAction like so:

```
- (IBAction)valueChanged:(UISwitch *)theSwitch {
    if (theSwitch.isOn) {
        NSLog(@"ON");    
    } else {
        NSLog(@"OFF");
    }
}
```

I need the use to be able to tap the last cell "Calculate" in order to move to another UIView with results.  How do I make #3 hidden unless On or OffGrid is set to ON?

Comment: Well, you can either remove the cell or gray it out.  Removing it is a simple matter of adjusting the counts and calling reload.  To gray it out you can simply set the cell's text color to gray and set a flag to disable touches on the cell, or you can get fancier by changing the background color, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the the ["Settings" example project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Settings/Settings/SettingsTableViewController.m) in the [TLIndexPathTools library](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools). It does exactly what you're asking for and more in a way that is very easy to manage.